# AAPT: error: failed writing to 'c: ....\r.txt': The data is invalid. (13)

Tags: android-studio, gradle

First off, I am a student learning the basics of app development in Android Studio.  With that in mind, please don't answer in short hand, acronyms or other technical jargon as I probably won't know what you are saying.

I have tried several fixes that appear across the web for this issue.  These fixes include, using the clean and rebuild options under Build in android studio.  Fully uninstalling and reinstalling Android Studio, running the program and creating a new app and then looking for the error, the invalidate cache / restart option under file and changing the android gradle plugin version and gradle version under Build > edit build types > project tab.  None of these have been successful.

The error popped up for me in September or early October after an update.  I was able to create my hello world app and our first simple app without any issues.  After the error appeared all apps refuse (including the ones that were working previously) to run or render in the emulator because of this error.  I have spent hours of 'office hours' with the instructor who has years of experience with android studio and this has him stumped as well.

I have 2 weeks of this course left and a final project to create.  I would be eternally grateful for a solution to this problem.

Thank you.

Comment: Is there a support line for Android Studio?  Where is the main source for help with the program?

Comment: 29 views, zero responses.  Still haven't solved the problem.  Clearly I am in the wrong place for help.